# How to integrate l7-filter option with linux iptables in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux

I did :

## mkdir /usr/local/iptables_l7

## cd /usr/local/iptables_l7

Download following packages from Debian source:

linux-2.6-2.6.32-amd64
netfilter-layer7-v2.22
l7-protocols-2009-05-28
iptables-1.4.8

Now i patch up kernel linux-2.6-2.6.32-amd64 with netfilter-layer7-v2.22/kernel-2.6.25-2.6.28-layer7-2.22.patch by the command

## patch -p1 < netfilter-layer7-v2.22/kernel-2.6.25-2.6.28-layer7-2.22.patch

Now copy netfilter-layer7-v2.22/iptables-1.4.3forward-for-kernel-2.6.20forward/libxt_layer7.c and netfilter-layer7-v2.22/iptables-1.4.3forward-for-kernel-2.6.20forward/libxt_layer7.man to iptables-1.4.8/extensions/

Then i compiled the kernel to activate layer7 and string match modules

## cd linux-2.6-2.6.32

## make menuconfig

i Check those options

Networking-->

Networking options -->

Network Packet Filtering framework (Netfilter) -->

Core Netfilter Configuration -->

under Core Netfilter Configuration option i can't found layer7 match suport option.